# Wordpress. How to find all external links in my posts?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to find all external links in my posts on my WP blog?

My site was hacked and they add some links to my posts. I want to see all external links in all posts and delete some of them?

Comment: Hey, I have found one link hope this will help if you try: https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/

Comment: This is the tip of the iceberg with your site.  Theres _much bigger concerns_ that you need to be worried about: what files have been compromised? How did the site get hacked? How do you prevent it getting hacked again? Changing ALL passwords (WP, cPanel, FTP, etc).  Be sure to a deep clean, otherwise this will happen again, and you'll just be wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

There are many SEO tools that could assist with something like this. An example of a tool that is reputable and I have used in the past is [Screaming Frog SEO Spider](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/). There may be some WordPress plugins that could be used for this as well, but I would be wary of using something like that. The links could very well be malicious and could further affect your WP install. Even if you use an external tool like SEO Spider, you may want to run it from a virtual / isolated machine in case the requests to the malicious links have successful exploits that could harm on your machine.